# How to create a mapping of string and struct array in solidity

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, remix

I am new to solidity trying to learn it.

I want to create a mapping like

```
mapping (string=>User[]) public  companyUserMap;
```

Where User is a struct

```
struct User {
   string userId;
   uint roleId;
}
```

Struggling with writing a function for adding / removing/ iterating a user to the mapping.

```
function addUser() {
    User usr= User("user01",1); 
    User usr2= User("user02",2);
    User usr[]={usr,usr2};
    //add the users created above to the mapping
    companyUserMap.push("c1",usr[])
}
```

> TypeError: Type struct AuthorizationManager.User memory is not implicitly convertible to expected type struct AuthorizationManager.User storage pointer.

Can someone please help me with functions for adding / removing / iterating the users and the mapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the basic patterns you need and you can base your more sophisticated getter/setter/remover functions on.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract AuthorizationManager{
    struct User{
      string userId;
      uint roleId;
    }

    mapping (string => User[]) companyUserMap;

    function addUser(string _key,string _userId, uint _roleId){
        companyUserMap[_key].push(User(_userId,_roleId));
    }

    function removeSingleUser(string _key){
        companyUserMap[_key].length--;
    }
}
```

Generally you should be really cautious when you iterate over large mappings, arrays etc. You could easily run out of gas and potentially lock your contract up. This is an **[instructive example](https://ethereum.karalabe.com/talks/2016-hackethon.html#7)**.